# Store last tweet ID of my followers which @mention me and have a hashtag

Tags: php, mysql, api, loops, twitter

I'd like store my followers latest status tweet containing that hashtag #RT and the mention of my name.

For example if one of my followers status was "HEY watch my video #RT @myusername" then I'd like to retweet this.

When you visit the following xml page we can get the followers last tweet.

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers/bbclick.xml

I'd just like to store the tweet id which @menion me and contain the hashtag #RT.

The ID would be stored in a mysql table using php.

I'm having difficulty looping through all my follower stauses.
I do understand that it'd have to be the last status update of my follower for this to work.

Can you please assist me.

Many Thanks,
ayathullah

Comment: Does the Tweet *have* to come from one of your followers?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than loop through all of your follower's statuses, you'd be better off just looping through all of the tweets that mention your name.  Twitter provides a method for this:

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/mentions

Then all you need to do is find the tweets that contain the "#RT".  Much easier.